# Given subspace $S\subset\mathbf{R}^n$, construct the matrix $A$ such that $S=\{x\mid Ax=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given subspace $S\subset\mathbf{R}^n$. How to construct a matrix $A$ such that $S=\{x\mid Ax=0\}$. Or prove there exists a matrix like that.

Comment: In what form are you given this subspace $S$? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_k)$ be a basis of $S$. Complete it, getting a basis $b=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the linear map $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into itself such that $f(e_i)=0$ if $i\leqslant k$ and that $f(e_i)=e_i$ otherwise. Then the matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a solution of your problem.